# Testing List<SelectOptions> method

Tags: apex, code-coverage

How should I go about increasing code coverage with the following code, other than proving that it is not empty.

```
    @isTest static void test_AppConfigList() {
    CustomSettingsManagementCtrl testCustomSettings = new CustomSettingsManagementCtrl();
    List<SelectOption> appConfigOptions = testCustomSettings.getAppConfigList();

    System.assert(appConfigOptions != null);
}
```

Also how would I go about testing an onSave method?

Answer (score 1):

Insert one or more picklist values in to your custom settings object, then you can validate that the picklist values returned have the expected value, label, and order.